# Average a columns in a 2D array with functional programming

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, functional-programming

As an exercise in functional programming, I've decided to go through one of my projects and replace functions containing for loops with `Array.prototype`'s *higher order functions* such as `map` and `reduce`.

One function in my project averages columns in a two dimensional array. It takes an arguments `samples` which is a 2d array of size `[n][LOOKBACK]`:

```
[
    [0.6,  4.0, -0.5],
    [1.0, -0.5, -0.8],
    ...
]
```

```js
const LOOKBACK = 3

function averageChange(samples) {
  let result = []
  let count = 0,
    i, j

  for (i = 0; i < LOOKBACK; i++) {

    let accumulator = 0

    for (j = 0; j < samples.length; j++) {
      accumulator += samples[j][i]
    }

    result.push(accumulator / samples.length)
  }

  return result
}

console.log(
  averageChange([
    [0.6, 4.0, -0.5],
    [1.0, -0.5, -0.8]
  ])
)
```

The output should be an array of size `LOOKBACK` who's elements are the average of each column:

```
[0.8, 1.75, -0.65]
```

I've spent some time trying to figure out a solution to this but I can't seem to come up with one.

**Is this possible using Javascript's built in Array functions?**

## *Update

Got an elegant solution from Kirill. If anyone else has a nice solution, I would love to see more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this example with `reduce` and `forEach` functions:

```js
let a = [
    [0.6,  4.0, -0.5],
    [3.0, -0.5, -0.1],
    [1.0, -0.2, -0.8],
    [7.0, -0.5, -0.8]
];

let b = a.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    cur.forEach((e, i) => acc[i] = acc[i] ? acc[i] + e : e);
    return acc;
}, []).map(e => e / a.length);

console.log(b);
```

Here is the more crafty method with matrix transpose:

```js
let a = [
    [0.6,  4.0, -0.5],
    [3.0, -0.5, -0.1],
    [1.0, -0.2, -0.8],
    [7.0, -0.5, -0.8]
];

let b = a[0].map((col, i) => a.map(row => row[i]).reduce((acc, c) => acc + c, 0) / a.length);

console.log(b);
```

Comment: I was on the same track with `reduce` and `forEach` but I couldn't quite get it. Seems kind of obvious now after seeing your example. That second solution is a beauty though. Nice job, thanks!

Comment: I get a js error on foreach.  `cur.forEach is not a function`

Comment: @just_a_programmerthis could happen if your input array contains any objects that are not arrays.

Answer (score 2):

## Intro..

Functional Programming is more than writing *one-liners* and using *higher-order functions* such as [`Arary#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Incidentally, [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not functional because it is not a *[pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)*..

In addition to *higher-order functions*, you can use [*currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), [*function composition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition), and [*more*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

## Algorithm

What we have to do is:

1. Rearrange the matrix
2. Calculate the avarage for each array inside the matrix

This could look in JavaScript like:

```
const averageChange = pipe(
    rearrange ([]),
    map (average) 
)
```

`pipe` is function to *compose* multiple functions to one huge function. `averageChange` takes now one argument and this will flow through the pipe.

#### Rearrange

```
const rearrange = yss => xss => 
    xss[0].length === 0
        ? yss
        : rearrange
            (concat (yss) ([ map ( getIndex (0) ) ( xss ) ]))
            (map ( slice (1, xss[0].length) ) ( xss ))
```

This looks really cryptic. Thanks to curry and functional composition we can rewrite it:

```
const rearrange = yss => xss => 
    matrixLength (xss) === 0
        ? yss
        : rearrange
            (concat (yss) ([ firstIndeces ( xss ) ]))
            (excludeFirstIndeces ( xss ))
```

`rearrange` is a recursive function that tranforms the matrix from

```
[
    [0.6,  4.0, -0.5],
    [3.0, -0.5, -0.1],
    [1.0, -0.2, -0.8],
    [7.0, -0.5, -0.8]
]
```

to

```
[ 
    [ -0.5, -0.1, -0.8, -0.8 ],
    [  4  , -0.5, -0.2, -0.5 ],
    [  0.6,  3  ,  1  ,  7   ] 
]
```

## Working Code Example

I have written much more code than the other solutions, but I divide the logic into my own functions, which means that we can now use function like `average` for other parts of our code. Also, I've written curryied versions for `Array#map` etc. to compose them. If you use a library, that would be superfluous..

```js
// helper functions
const pipe = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => g(f(...args)))

const getIndex = i => xs => 
    xs[i]

const map = f => xs =>
    xs.map(f)

const reduce = f => seel => xs =>
    xs.reduce(f)

const concat = ys => xs =>
    xs.concat(ys)

const slice = (start, end) => xs =>
    xs.slice(start, end)

const average = xs =>
    reduce ((sum, x) => sum + x) (0) (xs) / xs.length
    
const length = xs =>
  xs.length
    
const matrixLength = pipe(
  getIndex(0),
  length
)

const firstIndex = getIndex (0)

const firstIndeces = map ( firstIndex )

const excludeFirstIndex = xss => slice (1, matrixLength (xss)) (xss)

const excludeFirstIndeces = map ( excludeFirstIndex )
  
   
// business logic 
const rearrange = yss => xss => 
    matrixLength (xss) === 0
        ? yss
        : rearrange
            (concat (yss) ([ firstIndeces ( xss ) ]))
            (excludeFirstIndeces ( xss ))

const averageChange = pipe (
    rearrange ([]),
    map(average) 
)

const values = [
    [0.6,  4.0, -0.5],
    [3.0, -0.5, -0.1],
    [1.0, -0.2, -0.8],
    [7.0, -0.5, -0.8]
]

console.log( averageChange (values) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[];var b=[];
var i = 0; j = 0;

cubes.forEach(function each(item,length) {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    item.forEach(each);
    j++;
    i = 0;
  } else {
    if(a[i]===undefined){
        a[i]=0;b[i]=0}
    a[i]=(a[i]*b[i]+item)/(b[i]+1);
    b[i]=b[i]+1;
    i++;
  }
});
console.log(a);
```

this will work even for different inner array size.something like this [[1],[2,3,4]]

```js
cubes=[[1],[1,2,3]]
var a=[];var b=[];
var i = 0; j = 0;

cubes.forEach(function each(item,length) {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    item.forEach(each);
    j++;
    i = 0;
  } else {
    if(a[i]===undefined){
        a[i]=0;b[i]=0}
    a[i]=(a[i]*b[i]+item)/(b[i]+1);
    b[i]=b[i]+1;
    i++;
  }
});
console.log(a);
```